# Visio 2016 - Creating a Site Map

Tags: sitemap, visio

I've used Visio for many years now and having just installed Visio 2016 Professional, I tried to create a sitemap in the normal way but couldn't find the option to specify a URL/address to use - the wizard isn't automatically invoked, etc. It's definitely the "Professional" edition so the option should be available unless Microsoft have "streamlined" the product still further.

Does anyone know how to access/enable this feature or if it's even included any more?

The online help is utterly useless and I can only find one relevant article via Google which, unfortunately, doesn't provide a solution.

Thanks for looking :)

Answer (score 2):

For anyone with the same issue, downloading and installing the Visio 2016 SDK was the solution. Now, when I select "Web Site Map", under "Software", the wizard automatically runs and I'm able to enter a URL and generate a sitemap.